# Nested boost::assign:list_of broken in Visual Studio 2012 - ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012

This works in Visual Studio 2010, but it does not in 2012 Update 2 (with Boost 1.5.3):

```
vector<vector<BYTE>> data = assign::list_of (assign::list_of (0x06)(0x02));
```

The error given by the compiler (updated):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0(617): error C2668: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
   with
   [
       _Ty=BYTE
   ]
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(786): could be 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(std::vector<_Ty> &&)'
   with
   [
       _Ty=BYTE
   ]
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(693): or       'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(unsigned __int64)'
   with
   [
       _Ty=BYTE
   ]
   while trying to match the argument list '(boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>)'
   with
   [
   T=int
   ]
... (dozens of more lines)
```

Any way to work around this error?

Comment: please list possible matches from compiler output

Comment: @AndyT: I added more of the compiler's output.

Comment: Not so helpful, but relevant: VS12 should support initializer lists. You can write that code without Boost.Assign.

Comment: @pmr: While VS12 Update 1 brought support for initializer lists, the standard library was not adapted yet, so IL cannot be used with vector<>.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the problem is from embedding, it is from creating a temporary value using list_of.  That should work:

```
vector<BYTE> temp = assign::list_of (0x06)(0x02);
vector<vector<Byte> > data = assign::list_of(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VC11 so just a wild guess... Probably VC11 is confused because your integers can be converted to `BYTE` and so move-constructor would be used or to `size_t` and so `std::vector(size_t)` constructor would be used.

Please try to convert to `BYTE` yourself to avoid implicit conversion:

```
vector<vector<BYTE>> data = assign::list_of (assign::list_of (static_cast<BYTE>(0x06))(static_cast<BYTE>(0x02)));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. VS12 still says "ambiguous call to overloaded function".

Answer (score 0):

You need to help boost::assign::list_of a little with the template parameters:

```
// C2668:
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo1 = 
  boost::assign::list_of(boost::assign::list_of(0)(1));

// no C2668:
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo2 = 
  boost::assign::list_of<std::vector<int>>(boost::assign::list_of(0)(1));
```